# Typescript interface for custom map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have an interface like so:

```js
export interface IMyMap {
  [index: string]: RefObject<HTMLElement>;
}
```

Created as per the docs: [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

I would like to use this in a React `useState` hook, but I cant seem to make it work.
How would I go about actually using this interface?

Comment: Can you share your `useState` code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with `useState` like that

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState<IMyMap>({/* Your initial value here */});
```

Comment: I tried that, it accepted it, but the state was not turned into a map when I tried to use it.

Comment: Then you will need to provide more details into your question